# how to download Zip file to browser

Tags: php, laravel-4, zip

I am trying to download some images as a `zip` file to my download folder in pc. But it always downloaded to the projects public folder. What can be the issue?

Here is my code

```
$photos = json_decode(Input::get('photos'));
$dir = time();
foreach($photos as $file){
    $imgName = last(explode('/', $file));
    $path = public_path('downloads/'.$dir);


    if(!File::exists($path)){
        File::makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
    }

    ImageHandler::downloadFile($file, $path.'/'.$imgName);

}

$rootPath = realpath($path);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$file_name = 'photos.zip';
$zip->open( $file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file1)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file1->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file1->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath));

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

    }
}

$zip->close();


header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");

readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

Comment: This is not an issue about php. You code is correct. Your browser is responsible for choosing the right path. Check your browser settings for download folder.

Comment: @abeyaz anthying i download will save at the download folder except this.so browser settings correct

Comment: _“But it always downloaded to the projects public folder”_ - that is probably not an actual “download”, but just the zip file that was created during the process on the server side. // Have you checked in browser dev tools what actually happens when you try to trigger this download? Does an actual request happen, and what does it get answered with …?

Comment: @CBroe yes you're correct.how can i download that zip file through browser.this works fine upto zip file creation.

Comment: Well do you even get the download dialog presented by your browser - or what exactly happens? And I hope you have full PHP error reporting enabled, if not go do that now first.

Comment: @CBroe i am get nothing.only gives me 200 for the success of zip created.